# Values are being displayed by individual character

Tags: java, html, json, angularjs

So I currently have a HashMap being parsed into a table:

AngularJS:

(I believe this part is correct, but I'm happy to hear better solutions)

```
...
    var response = JSON.stringify(errorResponse.data.message).replace('=', ':');
                    $scope.listOfIds = JSON.parse(response);
...
```

This provides the output: `"{2:2140001793}"`

Now originally I was experiencing this error:

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: (key,entity) in importLog, Duplicate key: string:2, Duplicate value: 2
```

And I saw the solution was to pass this:

```
    <table ng-table="serviceNewTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,entity) in importLog track by $index">
            <td data-title="'ID'">
                {{key}}{{entity}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

However my output now is resulted in this:

[image]

As you can imagine, I would like it so that it shows the 2 and 214... on the same line but with two variables on the html (So key and value) and use said variables to call them. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When using $index, order is not guaranteed.  Based on your image, and what code you provided... My guess is that you are actually getting errors when you try to JSON.parse(response).  Because "{2:2140001793}" is not a valid JSON string.  To be a valid JSON string it would have to be: '{"2":2140001793}'. So when you parse, even if code execution seems to continue, your resultant object is just a string...  and when ng-repeat tries to iterate over it, its just grabbing individual chars... when you said to do (key, entity) its grabs 2 chars based on what ever order $index is using.

Answer (score 0):

The data you're processing is not a valid JSON. In this case the Key --> value, make the key as follows.

```
var data = {"1":123000123, "2":2140001793, "3":32145001};
```

JSON.parse accepts a second argument in the function that can do some post processing to get your expected result.

```
var output = JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `error.response.data` contains **JSON data** that is stored as a **string**.

So, we can use **angular.fromJson()** method to parse the `error.response.data` and bind it to a scope variable.

Now, in the view, we can use the `ng-repeat` to iterate over each `key, value` pairs and display it in a table.

#### In controller:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        // var response = error.response.data;   
        var response = '{"1":123000123, "2":2140001793, "3":32145001}';
        $scope.data = angular.fromJson(response);
     });
```

#### In View:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
       <td>{{ key }} </td>
       <td>{{ value }} </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image: Sample Output]